# \input inside \section

Tags: sectioning, input

Would you help me understand and possibly fix the problem below?

If I do

```
\title{\input{toBeIncluded.tex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test Section 1}

\section{Test Section 2}

\end{document}
```

I get exactly what I d expect (with no errors), whereas if I do

```
\title{Test Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{\input{toBeIncluded.tex}}

\section{Test Section 2}

\end{document}
```

I get two errors, even though the pdf is still produced and looks perfect.

toBeIncluded.tex is a file with just one word ("Hello") in it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please be aware that if you put that into section the toc entry may be problematic.

Comment: Thanks. For my current purpose that s fine since i have no toc. But good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ask this before? (someone did recently).

`\input` is a fragile command so you need

```
\section{\protect\input{toBeIncluded.tex}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! No - that s odd, since i googled quite a bit before asking. Where was it asked?